# Basis of a vector subspace in $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let H be the subspace of $P_2$ spanned by $-3x^2-2x+1, -2x-1 \ and\  -3x^2+6x+5$

a) A basis of H?

Solution: $\{-3x^2-2x+1,\ -2x-1\}$

b)  The dimension of H is?

Solution: 2

c) Is $\{-3x^2-2x+1, -2x-1,  -3x^2+6x+5\}$ a basis for $P_2$?

Solution: No

Can someone please check my solutions

Comment: yes, yes and yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-3x^2+6x+5 = 1(-3x^2-2x+5)-4(-2x-1)$$
It's a generating set for it, but since its elements aren't linearly independent, so it isn't a basis.
So your solution has no problem.